# Mongodb: sort documents by value in the last element of an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection '**collectionName**' with many documents like these:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f072d45856bc306147c1dcd"),
    "readOnly" : false,
    "participants" : [ 
        {
            "clientType" : "support",
            "docId" : "",
            "metaData" : {
                "fullName" : "Support",
                "email" : "Support@mydomain.com",
                "phoneNum" : "+1234567890"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "clientType" : "worker",
            "docId" : "5e21c48ee178473be81e032e",
            "metaData" : {
                "fullName" : "Rami",
                "email" : "myemail@gmail.com",
                "phoneNum" : "+1234567890"
            }
        }
    ],
    "messages" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "IGK-fIt-2zz",
            "sender" : "support, ",
            "body" : "CONTROL: Agent \"Greendizeriii\" has answered the conversation",
            "commData" : {
                "sent" : {
                    "state" : true,
                    "dateTime" : ISODate("2020-07-11T06:33:48.348Z")
                },
                "delivered" : {
                    "state" : false
                },
                "seen" : {
                    "state" : true,
                    "dateTime" : ISODate("2020-07-11T06:40:06.851Z")
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "L0f-hwj-QUL",
            "sender" : "support, ",
            "body" : "Hello rami, How can I help you today",
            "commData" : {
                "sent" : {
                    "state" : true,
                    "dateTime" : ISODate("2020-07-11T06:35:57.406Z")
                },
                "delivered" : {
                    "state" : false
                },
                "seen" : {
                    "state" : true,
                    "dateTime" : ISODate("2020-07-11T06:40:06.851Z")
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "n0k-s3u-UmN",
            "sender" : "support, ",
            "body" : "are you still there ?",
            "commData" : {
                "sent" : {
                    "state" : true,
                    "dateTime" : ISODate("2020-07-11T06:36:13.350Z")
                },
                "delivered" : {
                    "state" : false
                },
                "seen" : {
                    "state" : true,
                    "dateTime" : ISODate("2020-07-11T06:40:06.851Z")
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "controlData" : {
        "isReserved" : {
            "state" : false,
            "reservedUntil" : null,
            "operatorId" : null
        }
    },
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f1f143f4134643044638902"),
    "readOnly" : false,
    "participants" : [ 
        {
            "clientType" : "support",
            "docId" : "",
            "metaData" : {
                "fullName" : "Support",
                "email" : "Support@mydomain.com",
                "phoneNum" : "+1234567890"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "clientType" : "worker",
            "docId" : "5ea9409ff3243f483c2483ed",
            "metaData" : {
                "fullName" : "Ronaldo",
                "email" : "dummyemail02@gmail.com",
                "phoneNum" : "+1234567890"
            }
        }
    ],
    "messages" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "uto-qQb-0cr",
            "sender" : "support, ",
            "body" : "CONTROL: Agent \"Greendizeriii\" has answered the conversation",
            "commData" : {
                "sent" : {
                    "state" : true,
                    "dateTime" : ISODate("2020-07-27T17:51:59.753Z")
                },
                "delivered" : {
                    "state" : false
                },
                "seen" : {
                    "state" : true,
                    "dateTime" : ISODate("2020-07-27T17:52:01.240Z")
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "FQg-fSQ-jQ1",
            "sender" : "support, ",
            "body" : "jjj",
            "commData" : {
                "sent" : {
                    "state" : true,
                    "dateTime" : ISODate("2020-07-27T17:51:59.751Z")
                },
                "delivered" : {
                    "state" : false
                },
                "seen" : {
                    "state" : true,
                    "dateTime" : ISODate("2020-07-27T17:52:01.240Z")
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "Uqm-J4S-LUT",
            "sender" : "support, ",
            "body" : "CONTROL: Agent \"Greendizeriii\" has left the conversation",
            "commData" : {
                "sent" : {
                    "state" : true,
                    "dateTime" : ISODate("2020-07-27T17:53:05.142Z")
                },
                "delivered" : {
                    "state" : false
                },
                "seen" : {
                    "state" : true,
                    "dateTime" : ISODate("2020-07-27T17:53:05.558Z")
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "gs1-Qqz-jkI",
            "sender" : "worker, 5ea9409ff3243f483c2483ed",
            "body" : "Hello",
            "commData" : {
                "sent" : {
                    "state" : true,
                    "dateTime" : ISODate("2020-07-25T03:58:50.600Z")
                },
                "delivered" : {
                    "state" : false
                },
                "seen" : {
                    "state" : false
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "controlData" : {
        "isReserved" : {
            "state" : false,
            "reservedUntil" : null,
            "operatorId" : null
        }
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
```

for example here are two documents

each one has **messages** field which is an array of elements/objects

I want to sort them using (`commData.sent.dateTime`) of the latest element of messages array.

I know I can do something like :

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').find({}).sort({"messages.0.commData.sent.dateTime": 1})
```

which will return documents sorted using the commData.sent.dateTime of first element in messages array. but I don't know how to sort using the last element in the array in this particular situation.

**Note:**
The answer for question : [How to sort a collection using the last element of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126094/how-to-sort-a-collection-using-the-last-element-of-an-array)
will not work in my case since the field (dateTime) I need to use to sort the documents is inside a nested object

your help is so appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a collection using the last element of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126094/how-to-sort-a-collection-using-the-last-element-of-an-array)

Comment: Hey @Gibbs , The answer you suggested will not work in my case since the field (dateTime) I need to use to sort the documents is inside a nested object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) to calculate last sent date. [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) takes `-1` as a parameter which represents the last item of an array:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            lastSent: {
                $let: {
                    vars: {
                        last: {
                            $arrayElemAt: [ "$messages", -1 ]
                        }
                    },
                    in: "$$last.commData.sent.dateTime"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { $sort: { lastSent: 1 } },
    { $project: { lastSent: 0 } }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aToZNyAyTp5)

Comment: Thank you very much @mickl ✨ I was looking for this for almost a week now. I edited the answer and added a $projection stage after $sort, to remove lastSent field from output since it is no longer need.

Comment: @mickl
If I wanted to get the last object that matches a particular filter. How Can I use this?
For example, the last message that has a specific "sender".

Comment: @letie please open a separate question

Comment: @mickl I created this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65831571/sort-documents-by-value-in-the-last-element-of-an-array-that-matches-filter-mon