# Sort documents by value in the last element of an array that matches filter. Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sorting, filter, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of **evaluationGroups** with the following documents structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60073749694fd4d81e4d677d"),
    "AlertSettingId" : ObjectId("5ffddaaa0b1d2c30b191599a"),
    "CurrentStatus" : "success",
    "Evaluations" : [ 
        {
            "EvaluatedAt" : ISODate("2021-01-19T19:47:18.850Z"),
            "ReferenceValue" : 1.0,
            "Status" : "success"
        }, 
        {
            "EvaluatedAt" : ISODate("2021-01-19T19:52:16.423Z"),
            "ReferenceValue" : 1.0,
            "Status" : "triggered"
        }, 
        {
            "EvaluatedAt" : ISODate("2021-01-19T21:47:16.400Z"),
            "ReferenceValue" : 1.0,
            "Status" : "success"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60085ec60a264ce3829a6335"),
    "AlertSettingId" : ObjectId("5ffddaaa0b1d2c30b191599a"),
    "CurrentStatus" : "triggered",
    "Evaluations" : [ 
        {
            "EvaluatedAt" : ISODate("2021-01-20T18:03:01.040Z"),
            "ReferenceValue" : 1.0,
            "Status" : "noDataFound"
        }, 
        {
            "EvaluatedAt" : ISODate("2021-01-20T22:04:43.983Z"),
            "ReferenceValue" : 1.0,
            "Status" : "triggered"
        }, 
        {
            "EvaluatedAt" : ISODate("2021-01-20T22:39:43.978Z"),
            "ReferenceValue" : 1.0,
            "Status" : "triggered"
        }, 
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60099092f7386972de3e8a05"),
    "AlertSettingId" : ObjectId("5ffddaaa0b1d2c30b191599a"),
    "CurrentStatus" : "success",
    "Evaluations" : [ 
        {
            "EvaluatedAt" : ISODate("2021-01-21T14:32:48.697Z"),
            "ReferenceValue" : 1.0,
            "Status" : "noDataFound"
        }, 
        {
            "EvaluatedAt" : ISODate("2021-01-21T14:37:44.929Z"),
            "ReferenceValue" : 1.0,
            "Status" : "triggered"
        }, 
        {
            "EvaluatedAt" : ISODate("2021-01-21T14:42:44.928Z"),
            "ReferenceValue" : 1.0,
            "Status" : "triggered"
        }, 
        {
            "EvaluatedAt" : ISODate("2021-01-21T15:17:46.052Z"),
            "ReferenceValue" : 1.0,
            "Status" : "success"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I need to do is to **sort** all evaluation groups by the **latest** evaluation inside Evaluations (using `EvaluatedAt` property as the sort), but that the evaluation has also status **triggered**.

So, to sum up, I have to **sort the groups, by the latest triggered Evaluation date**.

I was looking at the question: [Mongodb: sort documents by value in the last element of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63140551/mongodb-sort-documents-by-value-in-the-last-element-of-an-array)

And I liked this response of how to sort by last item, (because latest evaluations are at the end of the array in my case):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            lastSent: {
                $let: {
                    vars: {
                        last: {
                            $arrayElemAt: [ "$messages", -1 ]
                        }
                    },
                    in: "$$last.commData.sent.dateTime"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { $sort: { lastSent: 1 } },
    { $project: { lastSent: 0 } }
])
```

But I would need to also filter evaluations by status "triggered" before getting the latest one.

How can achieve this using MongoDB **aggregate** query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$filter` operator,

- `$filter` to filter `Evaluations` array on the base of `Status`
- `$max` to get latest `EvaluatedAt` form filtered result

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      lastSent: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            filtered: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$Evaluations",
                cond: { $eq: ["$$this.Status", "triggered"] }
              }
            }
          },
          in: { $max: "$$filtered.EvaluatedAt" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { lastSent: 1 } },
  { $project: { lastSent: 0 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Qpl-lVg71S8)